# OData v3 dynamic navigation configuration using DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm currently trying to configure my OData service to use a DTO as the return type as it will have properties which will change from one request to another. The entities and the DTO(s) looks somewhat like the following:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<EntityB> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : IEntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... 

    public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntityB
{
    // Various properties
}

public class MyDTO
{
    public IEntityB { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<MySubDTO> SubDTOs { get; set; }
}

public class MySubDTO
{
    public string DynamicProp1 { get; set; }

    public string DynamicProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

Our OData config looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<EntityA>("EntityAs");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<EntityB>("EntityBs");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDTO>("MyDTOs");

var myDTOs = (EdmEntitySet)model.EntityContainers().Single().FindEntitySet("MyDTOs");
var myDTOType = (EdmEntityType)model.FindDeclaredType("MyApplication.DTO.MyDTO");

var entityAs = (EdmEntitySet)model.EntityContainers().Single().FindEntitySet("EntityAs");
var entityAType = (EdmEntityType)model.FindDeclaredType("MyApplication.DAL.Entities.EntityA");

var myDTOEntityANav = participantsType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo
{
    ContainsTarget = false,
    Name = "ActionableSchedules",
    Target = actionableSchedulesType,
    TargetMultiplicity = EdmMultiplicity.Many,
});

var entityAMyDTONav = actionableSchedulesType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo
{
    ContainsTarget = false,
    Name = "Participant",
    Target = participantsType,
    TargetMultiplicity = EdmMultiplicity.One,
});

myDTOs.AddNavigationTarget(entityAMyDTONav, entityAs);
entityAs.AddNavigationTarget(myDTOEntityANav, myDTOs);
```

When a request is received in the service the query in the controller method looks at the collection of EntityBs for a specific EntityA and based upon the values of certain properties on the EntityB we send back a IReadOnlyList with the EntityBs and we add a MySubDTO to the MyDTO which contains two string properties which differs from one request to another.

Everything works well up until the point where we're trying to send the response. The error that I get is:

> No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property
>   'EntityA' from entity type
>   'MyApplication.DTO.MyDTO' on entity set
>   'MyDTOs'. Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the
>   EntitySetConfiguration. Parameter name: navigationProperty

I tried to add the HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration and I ended up with a piece of code that looks like this:

```
entitySetConfiguration.HasNavigationPropertyLink(entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.NavigationProperties.First(np => np.Name == "EntityA"),
        (context, navigation) =>
    {
        return new Uri(context.Url.ODataLink(new EntitySetPathSegment("EntityA"),
            new KeyValuePathSegment(context.EntityInstance.EntityA.ID.ToString())));
    }, false);
```

And for this to work I had to change MyDTO to the following:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public IEntityB { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<MySubDTO> SubDTOs { get; set; }
}
```

And then update the OData config to the following:

```
var entitySetConfiguration = modelBuilder.EntitySet<MyDTO>("MyDTOs");
entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.HasOptional(p => p.EntityA);
```

> A property with name 'EntityA' on type 'MyApplication.DTO.MyDTO' has
>   kind 'None', but it is expected to be of kind 'Navigation'.

How should I configure my OData service to make this work?